# sending http request don't work correctly

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs4

i have an extjs 4 form and i'm sending information to save it on data base i'm using spring security and spring mvc

so in my extjs form in submit function i use this url

```
method:'POST', 
url: 'meeting/create.action',
```

and on my controller i use this

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/meeting/create.action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void add(MeetingUI data) {
        System.out.println("In add post method");

        MeetingUI savedUser = service1.create(data);
        if (savedUser != null) {
            logger.debug(" Created Succesfully");
        } else {
            logger.debug("Error trying to create account.");
        }
    }
```

no data was been received information saved in database as null
and other error shown

```
HTTP Status 404 - /writeup/WEB-INF/meeting/create.jsp
```

i dont want that /meeting/create.action  is integrated with spring security i think that's the error

please any one have a solution

Answer (score 0):

Your handler method has a return type of `void`. Reading section 13.11.4. Supported handler method arguments and return types in the [Spring MVC Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/mvc.html), you see that

> void if the method handles the response itself (by writing the
>   response content directly, declaring an argument of type
>   ServletResponse / HttpServletResponse for that purpose) or if the view
>   name is supposed to be implicitly determined through a
>   RequestToViewNameTranslator (not declaring a response argument in the
>   handler method signature).

The only Spring implementation of `RequestToViewNameTranslator` is `DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator` which says

> RequestToViewNameTranslator that simply transforms the URI of the
>   incoming request into a view name.

and

> Find below some examples of request to view name translation.
>
> `http://localhost:8080/gamecast/display.html` -> display

Which would map your URI of `/meeting/create.action` to `meeting/create`. I then assume you have some ViewResolver for `jsp` files. This probably prefixes that path with `/WEB-INF/` and suffixes it with `.jsp`, ending up as `/WEB-INF/meeting/create.jsp` which you probably don't have, thus `404`.

Make your method return a String of the view name or make it write to the response body itself.

Your method might look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/meeting/create.action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Stringadd(MeetingUI data) {
    System.out.println("In add post method");

    MeetingUI savedUser = service1.create(data);
    if (savedUser != null) {
        logger.debug(" Created Succesfully");
        return "success";
    } else {
        logger.debug("Error trying to create account.");
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: @Amin just changed your method to something like above, where `success` maps to some jsp named `success.jsp`, and same for `error`.

Comment: i work only with extjs i have one jsp page that is used to load extjs scripts

Comment: @Amin How does extjs decide which script to run?